32 bit OS crashes after jumping to reload the code segment
Here's the code for resetting the segments:
global reloadSegments

section .text
    reloadSegments:
       ; Reload the CS register with an offset of 0x08
       jmp 0x08:.reload_CS
    .reload_CS:
       ; Reload data segment registers
       mov ax, 0x10
       mov ds, ax
       mov es, ax
       mov fs, ax
       mov gs, ax
       mov ss, ax
       ret

The jump itself is what crashes the os.
Here's the code for loading the gdt:
void lgdt(void* gdt, uint16_t size) {
    gdtr.base = (uint32_t)gdt;
    gdtr.limit = size-1;
    asm __volatile__("lgdt (%0)" : : "r" (&gdtr));
}

The base is 32 bit value while the limit is 16.
Here's where I call both functions and fill the gdt:
void initGdt() {
    create_descriptor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    create_descriptor(1, 0, 0x000FFFFF, (GDT_CODE_PL0));
    create_descriptor(2, 0, 0x000FFFFF, (GDT_DATA_PL0));
    create_descriptor(3, 0, 0x000FFFFF, (GDT_CODE_PL3));
    create_descriptor(4, 0, 0x000FFFFF, (GDT_DATA_PL3));

    lgdt(&gdt, sizeof(gdt)-1);
    extern void reloadSegments();
    reloadSegments();
}

The functions and constants for creating descriptors are all from the gdt tutorial at osdev.org. I'm using the QEMU as a virtual machine with multiboot. Here's a link to the project's github: https://github.com/Wardence1/Basic_OS
I expected os to successfully jump to the reload_CS label and reload the cs register without problem. Thanks in advance for the help!

I don;t see the bug within this code. It could be something you aren't showing us including how you build the code and if you are using a custom bootloader (rather than GRUB or Limine etc) there could be bugs in that like not reading enough sectors to load the entire kernel, the ORG being used, or a problem in the linker script. What we really need is a [mcve]. Do you have this project on Github? Using a debugger in BOCHS would probably help finding low level issues like this. Are you even sure it isn't failing sometime after you execute this code?

There is one potential bug asm __volatile__("lgdt (%0)" : : "r" (&gdtr)); should be asm __volatile__("lgdt %0" : : "m" (gdtr)); . There is a subtle but important difference. Your version passes the register into the inline assembly, but doesn't ensure that what the register points at is realized into memory before executing the inline assembly.

@MichaelPetch I've added a link to the repo and the virtual machine I'm using. The os runs just fine if ret is put before the jump.

@MichaelPetch That's smart, I'm only used to loading values into registers with inline asm lol, however it's still crashing. ):

What were the previous contents of the descriptor table, and what segments were previously used for CS/DS/etc?

uint16_t gdt[5]; That ain't right.  Needs to be uint64_t, no?  Also, you subtracted 1 from the gdt size twice?

I agree with the @NateEldredge uint16_t gdt[5] needing to be uint64_t gdt[5] but I also see that in struct for gdtr you have the base before limit where it needs to be after.

Bochs's built-in debugger can pretty-print the GDT so you can see exactly how your data structures are interpreted by the guest CPU.  That and single-stepping the (compiler-generated) asm with the debugger and checking memory contents should help reveal whether problems still exist, and hopefully point you in the direction of what type of problem.  e.g. a wrong limit should be easy for a debugger to reveal.

@MichaelPetch: With respect to the inline asm operands, don't we have the same issue one level deeper?  The m operand forces gdtr to be populated before the asm, but doesn't force gdt itself to be populated, since that is not an operand.  So I suppose the compiler could reorder the stores to gdt after the lgdt, and then of course it would break.  Maybe we could stack up some more m operands, but at this point, it's probably safest to just use a "memory" clobber.

Using a memory operand is probably he safest option for the extra level of indirection. I usually use a memory constraint and a memory clobber.

@MichaelPetch: Yeah, probably best not to let GCC reorder any memory operations around something as critical as lgdt.  If it perhaps costs you a few extra bytes of machine code because a dead store is not eliminated when it safely could have been, that's still usually worth it for the benefit of being a lot more sure that it's not reordering something important that could lead to breakage.  Instructions that execute once per boot don't matter for performance, unlike inline asm that's going to be used regularly, especially inside a loop.

On my last comment there was a typo. Should have been memory clobber not memory operand

This answer is the culmination of everything the fine folks in the comments have said. First of all the gdt should be made up of 64 bit entries, not 16 bit. Second of all the limit should be placed in the struct for the gdtr before the base. Third of all I subtracted from gdt's size twice, once in the lgdt function args and once in the lgdt function itself. To make the code safer I switched the "r" with a "m" in the inline asm and passed a value into the gdtr. Thank you all again for the comments and support!

While it isn't causing an issue yet you probably will want to change gdtr.limit = size-1; to gdtr.limit = size; since you are already subtracting 1 when you do lgdt(&gdt, sizeof(gdt)-1); . The result is subtracting 2 for the size. This was also pointed out by Nate in the question's comments.

@MichaelPetch I fixed it in the os but forgot to add it to the answer, I'll edit it now.
